# Setup blocked when installing DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

I am installing `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe` on windows 10.
My Visual Studio version is VS2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3.
I am facing below errors when running the exe. I also i have tried to install via command `DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1`. Still it throws below error.
Error Log:

```
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i001: Burn v3.10.3.3007, Windows v10.0 (Build 10586: Service Pack 0), path: C:\Users\subburay\AppData\Local\Temp\{D146C1B0-5942-49DF-9250-5E8831C2DC52}\.cr\DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CHECK_SETUP_BLOCKED' to value '1'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SKIP_VSU_CHECK' to value '0'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SKIP_PREPARATION' to value '0'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Initializing string variable 'BundleNameShort' to value 'Microsoft .NET Core 1.0.1'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Initializing string variable 'BundleNameSub' to value 'VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=428 -burn.filehandle.self=436 SKIP_VSU_CHECK=1'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\DotNetCore.1.0.1-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.3.exe'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\subburay\AppData\Local\Temp\dd_DotNetCoreTools__20170327104052.log'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Microsoft Corporation'
[1834:1450][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'SKIP_VSU_CHECK' to value '1'
[1834:1450][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting numeric variable 'WixStdBALanguageId' to value 1033
[1834:1450][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '1.0.21114.69'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i100: Detect begin, 99 packages
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Product or related product not found: {2DD0A7D2-C8FA-46FC-AB7B-6218BD77E641}
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting version variable 'DotNetCLIProductVersion_x64' to value '0.0.0.0'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i052: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i052: Condition 'VersionNT64' evaluates to true.
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Product or related product not found: {A57B8D12-9DCD-462D-8381-3EE1154305F1}
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting version variable 'DotNetRedistProductVersion_x64' to value '0.0.0.0'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i052: Condition 'NOT VersionNT64' evaluates to false.
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Setting string variable 'IISExpressVersion_x64' to value '10.0.1736'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Registry value not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\IISExpress', Value = 'Version'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components'
[1834:2AE0][2017-03-27T10:40:52]i052: Condition 'NOT (((IISCoreWebEngineInstalled_x86=1) AND (IISW3SVCInstalled_x86=1)) OR ((IISCoreWebEngineInstalled_x64=1) AND (IISW3SVCInstalled_x64=1)))' evaluates to true.
```